# Implementing SP Initiated SSO using OpenID Connect in PingOne

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am in the current process of doing a SP(Service Provider) Initiated SSO.

- The IdP(Identity Provider) is PingOne
- The SP is my own application

We have the IdP Initiated SSO setup and everything is working perfectly. We have now to make it SP Initiated.

Is there any possible ways to implement the SP initiated SSO in PingOne(as IdP). Since I didn't find any clue to implement this approach.

Can you guys please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

OIDC is supported on PING Federate but does not seem to be the case with PING One.
You may want to reach out to PING Identity support.

Answer (score 0):

Ping does support SP-initiated SSO, but it's been my experience that most Ping IdP users don't understand the difference, or only want to support IdP-initiated SSO. The main reason for that is that you'll need to construct your own SAML metadata to support SP-initiated SSO, and the ACS URLs are different in the SP-initiated case.

For the proper URLs see: https://ping.force.com/Support/PingOne/PingOne-General/PingOne-How-to-configure-SP-initiated-SSO

FWIW I've had good luck with Ping support in the past. Just ask your client to open a ticket with them and they will sort you out.